# Java Flux GroupedFlux count() print

Tags: java, project-reactor

Hi rectors all aver the world. I'm doing reactivi programming in Java. I'm a java/grails/react developer but first steps with reactive programming with Spring Boot, version 2 M7 in this case. In the next code:

```
@GetMapping(API_BASE_PATH + "/flux4")
public String flux4() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Flux.just("alpha", "bravo", "charlie")
        .map(String::toUpperCase)
        .flatMap(s -> Flux.fromArray(s.split("")))
        .groupBy(String::toString)
        .sort(Comparator.comparing(GroupedFlux::key))
        .map(group -> group.key() + " => " + group.count() + "; ")
        .subscribe(sb::append);

    return "flux 4: " + sb.toString();
}
```

I get the group.key() printed but how caon I get printed the group.count() ?

Any help is welcome

Cheers

Juan

Comment: The current output is:flux 4: A => MonoCount; B => MonoCount; C => MonoCount; E => MonoCount; H => MonoCount; I => MonoCount; L => MonoCount; O => MonoCount; P => MonoCount; R => MonoCount; V => MonoCount;

Comment: group.count().block() probably fails, right?

Comment: What happens if you try to get the count in the subscribe instead of the map?

Comment: Yes you arer right `group.count().block()`, It's working now. Should has more sense as you say "try to get the count in the subscribe instead of the map". Thanks Kylos !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I am reading the same book as you :)

Here is the solution using `block()`.

```
        Flux.just("alpha", "beta", "charlie")
        .map(String::toUpperCase)
        .flatMap(s -> Flux.fromArray(s.split("")))
        .groupBy(String::toString)
        .sort((o1,o2) -> o1.key().compareTo(o2.key()))
        .flatMap(group -> Mono.just(Tuples.of(group.key(), group.count().block()))) 
        .map(keyAndCount -> keyAndCount.getT1() + " => " + keyAndCount.getT2() + "; ")
```

I am wondering if there is an alternate way that doesn't call `block()`?. Now `group.count()` returns a `Mono<Long>`, and `group.key()` returns a `String`. It would be good if we could combine the two to form a `Mono<Tuple2<String, Long>>` without having to evaluate the result of the Mono. Seems like there should be a general method for doing that?

The book tried to use:

```
Mono.just(group.key()).and(group.count())
```

But that just listens for the completion events and returns a `Mono<Void>`, and therefore gives me compile errors...

Addendum: found it! Use the `zip` method:

```
    Flux.just("alpha", "beta", "charlie")
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .flatMap(s -> Flux.fromArray(s.split("")))
    .groupBy(String::toString)
    .sort((o1,o2) -> o1.key().compareTo(o2.key()))
    .flatMap(group -> Mono.zip(Mono.just(group.key()), group.count()))
    .map(keyAndCount -> keyAndCount.getT1() + " => " + keyAndCount.getT2() + "; ")
```

Comment: or Mono.just(group.key())
.zipWith(group.count())

Comment: May I ask what book are you talking about?

Comment: It was a long time ago, I don't remember anymore.